# Dynamically change dropdown options when one option is selected in Python Dash

Tags: python, dropdown, plotly-dash

I have a dropdown of 4 values, ['All', 'a', 'b', 'c'], where I can select many of them.

```
dcc.Dropdown(
    id='test',
    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['All', 'a', 'b', 'c']],
    value='All',
    clearable=False,
    multi=True,
),
```

Now, is it possible to dynamically change the options, such that when 'All' is used, all other selected entries are removed automatically?
Something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('test', 'options'),
    Input('test', 'value'),
)
def update_ticker_options(value):
    if 'All' in value:
        ticker = 'All'
    return ticker
```

The app is not starting with this code, so it is not working.

Comment: Change the output of callback from `options` to `value`

Comment: Not working when changing options to value as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Ibrahim,

I modified your answer even a bit further, since I want it to show 'All' and not all other values. This code does the work:

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='test',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['All', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']],
        value='All',
        clearable=False,
        multi=True,
    ),
)


@app.callback(
    Output('test', 'value'),
    Input('test', 'value'),
)
def update_ticker_options(value):
    ticker = value
    if 'All' in value and value[0] != 'All':
        ticker = ['All']
    elif 'All' in value:
        ticker = value[1]
    return ticker
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your example code based on the functionality you need. Basically what you need is to change the `Output` parameter to be `value` as shown below. What should happen is when `all` is selected all the other options should be added which I included in a list as an example. This list should be returned to the  `value` parameter in the dropdown.

```py
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['All', 'a', 'b', 'c']],
                value='a',
                clearable=False,
                multi=True,
            ),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('dropdown', 'value'),
)
def update_ticker_options(value):
    if 'All' in value:
        value = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return value
```